# How to record WebSphere MQ FTE transfer result in a local queue?

Tags: ant, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

How to record WebSphere MQ FTE transfer result in a local queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an administrative subscription to the WMQ FTE transfer publications and direct it to the queue where you wish these events to be reported.

```
DEFINE QL(MY.LOCAL.QUEUE) +
   REPLACE

DEFINE SUB(FTE.TRANSER.RESULTS) +
   DEST(MY.LOCAL.QUEUE) +
   TOPICSTR('SYSTEM.FTE/#') +
   REPLACE
```